# Error doing a Full Outer Join

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

`product` table:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════╗
║               ref                ║    mfr    ║       pnum        ║        ssku        ║ id ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════╣
║ 6541_aten_2a-130g                ║ Aten      ║ 2A-130G           ║ 2A-130G            ║  6 ║
║ 7466_eaton_5sc1000i              ║ Eaton     ║ 5SC1000I          ║                    ║  8 ║
║ 8214_ivanti-uk_template-material ║ IVANTI UK ║ TEMPLATE MATERIAL ║ 000000000003616655 ║  4 ║
║ 8361_aywun_92sfan1               ║ Aywun     ║ 92SFAN1           ║ 92SFAN             ║  9 ║
║ 9824_autodesk_00100-000000-9880  ║ AUTODESK  ║ 00100-000000-9880 ║ 00100-000000-9880  ║  5 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════╝
```

`inventory` table:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═══════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║               ref                ║ scost ║ instock ║        date         ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 6541_aten_2a-130g                ║    26 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
║ 7466_eaton_5sc1000i              ║   489 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
║ 8214_ivanti-uk_template-material ║     0 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
║ 8361_aywun_92sfan1               ║     4 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
║ 9824_autodesk_00100-000000-9880  ║   738 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═══════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

... and I'm looking to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (get columns from both tables only if key exists in both if I understand correctly?) using [Medoo](https://medoo.in/api/select):

```
$data = $database->select("product", [
    "[<>]inventory" => ["ref" => "ref"],
]);
```

Error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/vendor/catfan/medoo/src/Medoo.php on line
```

I also tried these queries in the console but getting a syntax error:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
FULL OUTER JOIN product ON product.ref = inventory.ref;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `product`, * FROM `inventory` 
WHERE product.`ref` = inventory.`ref`;
```

**Expected result:**

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╦════╦═══════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║        ref        ║ mfr  ║  pnum   ║  ssku   ║ id ║ scost ║ instock ║        date         ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════╬════╬═══════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 6541_aten_2a-130g ║ Aten ║ 2A-130G ║ 2A-130G ║  6 ║    26 ║       0 ║ 2017-05-27 10:45:23 ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╩════╩═══════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Each `ref` seems to be the same in two tables. Why your expected result has only one record. And your sql `join` the same table `product`.

Comment: @Forward Ah, is that the problem? I'm new to MySQL so had no clue about relational db. Now I understand, column names should be different I guess, thats why its not working.

Comment: @Forward This my DB structure: https://pastebin.com/6A0E1xUM

Comment: All those tables join together with `ref`?

Comment: Erm yes, please forgive my stupidity. first time created a db.

Comment: Try the answer I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, and your logic seems to be `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
INNER JOIN inventory ON product.`ref` = inventory.`ref`;
```

But I don't know why in two tables the `ref`'s are all the same, your expected result only have one record, and according to  Medoo document, the code should be like following:

```
$data = $database->select(
   "product",
    [
       "[><]inventory" => "ref"
    ],
    "*");
```

For all of your tables, try this:

```
$data = $database->select(
   "product",
    [
       "[><]inventory" => "ref",
       "[><]detail" => "ref",
       "[><]moredetails" => "ref",
       "[><]info" => "ref",
       "[><]images" => "ref",
       "[><]features" => "ref",
       "[><]categories" => "ref",
       "[><]tags" => "ref"
    ],
    ["product.*", "inventory.*"]);
```

Comment: Just noticed the only issue that it shows the first row twice.